# Changing the points shape in fviz_pca_biplot

Tags: shapes, pch, biplot

I am plotting my PCA as a biplot with

```
fviz_pca_biplot
```

but I cannot change my points to squares (pch=15).

For single group of observations I use the code as below

```
basic_bi_plot <- fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, axes = c(1, 2),
                                 pointsize = 3,
                                 addEllipses = FALSE, label = "var", labelsize = 10, 
                                 col.var="contrib",
                                 gradient.cols = c("grey75", "blue", "red"),
                                 repel = TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95)

basic_bi_plot


try_bi.plot <-  basic_bi_plot  + 
  My_Theme  +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15))
```

but the

```
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15))
```

is not changing anything and I keep getting the default circles.

Answer (score 0):

You might have figured it out by now but in case it can help someone else, try adding `point = 15` in your `fviz_pca_biplot`function. It worked on my data.

```
fviz_pca_biplot(pca, axes = c(1, 2),pointsize = 3,point = 15,label = "var)
```